# python - Аудио файл не может быть прочитан

Tags: python, аудио, распознавание-речи

Скачиваю файл с апишки телеграмма и даю прочесть его библиотеке speech recognition, но она выдаёт данную ошибку:

> Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format

```
def recognition_voice(url):
    download_file(url)

    r = sr.Recognizer()

    file_audio = sr.AudioFile('voice_message.ogg')

    with file_audio as source:
         audio_text = r.record(source)

    print(type(audio_text))
    print(r.recognize_sphinx(audio_text))
```

Перепробовал все способы которые нашёл, ни один не помог (там где не нужно было скачивать дополнительного ПО), в частности с использованием таких библиотек, как: pydub, soundfile, wavio.
Если кто-то знает решение данной проблемы пожалуйста ответьте. Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Попробуйте библиотеку pafy https://pythonhosted.org/pafy/

Comment: @Сергей в pafy, как я понимаю, нужно конкретно видео и тогда из него уже можно будет вытащить аудио дорожку, в моём случаи я уже имею готовый аудио файл, который я скачиваю с api телеграмма (голосовое сообщение).

Comment: попробуй произвести конвертацию скачаного файла в иной распознаваемый формат

Comment: @ganz с помощью pydub я пытался конвертировать, но как я понял там нужно иметь установленный ffmpeg, что уже не подходит под мои требования (стороннее ПО, не библиотека). Если знаешь какие-нибудь библиотеки которые могут это сделать, подскажи пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот нашел детище майкрософт, пишут что поддерживается сжатый формат ogg/opus, может поможет https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-codec-compressed-audio-input-streams?tabs=windows%2Cdebian&pivots=programming-language-python